# Can't close my file

Tags: java

I used Formatter to create my file, and when I try to close it the finally block it says instance variable hasn't been initialized, however it works if I close it in my try block, but I don't want to do that. Also, side note, I don't know if I am using my exceptions correctly either because I don't know what two of them are.

```
public class NewFile
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {

final Formatter file;

    try// create file
    {
    file = new Formatter("Records.txt");

     Account[] records = new Account[4];

      records[ 0 ] = new Account( 100, "January", "Smith", 34.56 );
      records[ 1 ] = new Account( 200, "Sally", "Anderson", 467.10 );
      records[ 2 ] = new Account( 300, "Joe", "Wright", -67.60 );
      records[ 3 ] = new Account( 400, "Henry", "Hein", 0.00 );


   for(Account display : records)
       {
      file.format("\n %d %s %s %,.2f\n", display.getAccount(),display.getFirst(), display.getLast(), display.getBalance());
   }
    }

   catch(FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException)
    {
      System.err.println("File not found.");
    }
      catch(SecurityException securityException)
    {
      System.err.println("Do not have required permission.");
    }

       catch(FormatterClosedException formatterClosedException)
    {
      System.err.println("File is already closed.");
    }

    catch(IllegalStateException illegalStateException)
    {
      System.err.println("Error reading from file.");
    }

    finally//close the file
    {
    file.close();
    }
 }
```

Ok here is what I have now after comments:

```
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.lang.IllegalStateException;
import java.lang.SecurityException;
import java.util.FormatterClosedException;

public class NewFile
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {

 Formatter file;

    try// create file
    {
    file = new Formatter("Records.txt");

     Account[] records = new Account[4];

      records [ 0 ] = new Account( 100, "January", "Smith", 34.56 );
      records[ 1 ] = new Account( 200, "Sally", "Anderson", 467.10 );
      records[ 2 ] = new Account( 300, "Joe", "Wright", -67.60 );
      records[ 3 ] = new Account( 400, "Henry", "Hein", 0.00 );


   for(Account display : records)
       {
      file.format("\n %d %s %s %,.2f\n", display.getAccount(),display.getFirst(), display.getLast(), display.getBalance());
   }
    }

   catch(FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException)
    {
      System.err.println("File not found.");
    }
      catch(SecurityException securityException)
    {
      System.err.println("Do not have required permission.");
    }

       catch(FormatterClosedException formatterClosedException)
    {
      System.err.println("File is already closed.");
    }

    catch(IllegalStateException illegalStateException)
    {
      System.err.println("Error reading from file.");
    }

    finally//close the file
    {
      if(file != null)
      {
    file.close();
      }
    }
    }
 }
```

And this is the error:
variable file might not have been initialized

Comment: If an exception occurs during execution of the very first line of the `try` block then indeed the variable `file` will not be initialized.

Comment: Ok, but I don't see where there would be an exception that occurred. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: @user3772253: chit, you still don't initialize it to `null`!! Please re-read the 2nd line of my answer.

Comment: I did and it still didn't work I tried both ways.

Comment: I am sorry, I tried it again and it worked this time, I guess when I tried it I missed something. Sorry, and thank you!

Comment: also, I had tried before uploading new code, and when I tried it, it didn't work for me at the time, that is why I didn't put it on here. Just so you know.

Comment: An exception could occur in `new Formatter`.  If that happened, `file` would be uninitialized.  Java does not allow uninitialized variables to be referenced, period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change `final Formatter file;` to

```
Formatter file = null;
```

Note that I don't believe that can be `final` for this to work, but this way, the compiler will see that the file variable will been initialized to something.

Then in finally, check for null:

```
finally {
   if (file != null) {
      file.close();
   }
}
```

---

**Edit**
Or as per MadProgrammer, use Java 7's try with resources.

```
try (Formatter file = new Formatter("Records.txt")) {
    // do stuff with file here

} catch(FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
      System.err.println("File not found.");
} catch(SecurityException securityException) {
      System.err.println("Do not have required permission.");
} catch(FormatterClosedException formatterClosedException) {
      System.err.println("File is already closed.");
} catch(IllegalStateException illegalStateException) {
      System.err.println("Error reading from file.");
}
```

Comment: Or use java 7's try-with-resources ;)

Comment: I was just posting it.

Comment: Nope, still saying it can't find the symbol file. For some reason it doesn't recognize it even though I put Formatter file before the main method. I also tried declaring it in the main method too and it's saying same thing. I don't understand why it's giving me that same error.

Comment: @user3772253: It works for me. If you've changed your code and are getting errors, then show the code and the error as an edit to the end of your original question. Don't paraphrase and say that it's not working since we can't do much to help you with that.

Comment: Ok I will add what I have now.

Comment: @user3772253: sigh. The most important recommendation given was ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This code compiles for me (I had to fudge the Account class):

```
public class NewFile
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Formatter file = null;
        try
        // create file
        {
            file = new Formatter("Records.txt");

            Account[] records = new Account[4];

            records[0] = new Account(100, "January", "Smith", 34.56);
            records[1] = new Account(200, "Sally", "Anderson", 467.10);
            records[2] = new Account(300, "Joe", "Wright", -67.60);
            records[3] = new Account(400, "Henry", "Hein", 0.00);

            for (Account display : records)
            {
                file.format("\n %d %s %s %,.2f\n", display.getAccount(), display.getFirst(), display.getLast(),
                            display.getBalance());
            }
        }

        catch (final FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException)
        {
            System.err.println("File not found.");
        }
        catch (final SecurityException securityException)
        {
            System.err.println("Do not have required permission.");
        }

        catch (final FormatterClosedException formatterClosedException)
        {
            System.err.println("File is already closed.");
        }

        catch (final IllegalStateException illegalStateException)
        {
            System.err.println("Error reading from file.");
        }

        finally
        // close the file
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                file.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```